# The Definitive JUnit/Parallel/ANT Issue

Tags: ant, junit, parallel-processing, junit4

What is the cleanest way to Run Test1.java and Test2.java via ANT in Parallel taking into consideration that Test1.java and Test2.java have one test method inside. And what if the scenario was one class with multiple test methods? how to dynamically select which ones you want executed? and have reports for everything executed. I have seen this everywhere and have not seen a solid answer pointing to these problems.